# hkworkout totalenergyburned doesn't correlate with HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

This is more of a data structure question than a programming syntax question. The data structure of the Health app is somewhat of a black box.

I want to query HKHealthStore and create both a daily summary of items including, ActiveEnergyBurned,  and also a summary of workouts including totalEnergyBurned.

I have code (below) that successfully retrieves this information. However the number for the daily total is usually LESS than that day's workout! I am sure that my code is not the problem, because the exact same numbers show up in the Apple Health app. For example:

yesterday's workout: 
My app
workout.totalEnergyBurned = 905 kcal
sum of yesterday's ActiveEnergyBurned 655 kcal
Health app shows the exact same numbers for both.

If ActiveEnergyBurned, doesn't include workouts, what does it include? I didn't have another 655 of ActiveEnergyBurned. It doesn't seem possible to me that ActiveEnergyBurned wouldn't include workouts!

```
   //to get sum of day's activeCaloriesBurned:

func getActiveCalories(startDate:NSDate, endDate:NSDate){
    let sampleType =      HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)
    let hkUnit = HKUnit.kilocalorieUnit()

    getSumStatsFor(sampleType, hkUnit: hkUnit, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate) { (hdObject, result) -> Void in
        hdObject.activeCalories = result
    }
}

func getTotalsForDataType(quantitiyType:HKQuantityType, startDate:NSDate,      endDate:NSDate, completion:(HKStatisticsCollection!, NSError!) -> Void){
    println("getTotalsForDataType start: \(startDate) end: \(endDate)")
    let dayStart = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(startDate)
    let addDay = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: 1, toDate: endDate, options:nil)
    let dayEnd = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(addDay!)  //add one day
    let interval = NSDateComponents()
    interval.day = 1

    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, options: HKQueryOptions.None)
    let newQuery = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: quantitiyType,
                                    quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
                                                    options: HKStatisticsOptions.CumulativeSum,
                                                 anchorDate: dayStart,
                                         intervalComponents: interval)
    newQuery.initialResultsHandler = {
        query, results, error in
        if error != nil {
            println("*** An error occurred while calculating the statistics: \(error.localizedDescription) ***")
            completion(nil, error)
        }else{
            completion(results,error)
        }
    }
  self.healthKitStore.executeQuery(newQuery)
}

//to get workout totalCalories burned

func readWorkouts(completion: (([AnyObject]!, NSError!) ->Void)!){
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: false)
    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: HKWorkoutType.workoutType(), predicate: nil, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (sampleQuery, results, error) -> Void in
            if let queryError = error {
            println( "There was an error while reading the samples: \(queryError.localizedDescription)")
        }
        completion(results,error)
    }
    healthKitStore.executeQuery(sampleQuery)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to a bug with how the HealthKit workout API was designed. With the current API it's possible for 3rd party apps to create `HKWorkout`s where `totalEnergyBurned` is greater than 0, but no associated `HKSamples` of the `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned` type are created to sum up to `totalEnergyBurned`. As an example, a 3rd party app that feeds workout data into HealthKit could do this:

```
HKHealthStore *healthStore = [HKHealthStore new];
HKWorkout *workout = [HKWorkout workoutWithActivityType:HKWorkoutActivityTypePlay
                                               startDate:[NSDate date]
                                                 endDate:[NSDate date]
                                                duration:100.0
                                       totalEnergyBurned:[HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit kilocalorieUnit] doubleValue:445]
                                           totalDistance:[HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit meterUnit] doubleValue:1000]
                                                metadata:nil];
[healthStore saveObject:workout withCompletion:nil];
```

Note that nowhere are any `HKSamples` created of type `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned`. Then when you sum up the active energy burned for the day and compare it to the workout's total energy burned you will get 0 kcal vs 445 kcal. What a good 3rd party app would do is this after creating the workout:

```
NSArray *workoutSamples = @[[HKQuantitySample quantitySampleWithType:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned
                                                            quantity:[HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit kilocalorieUnit] doubleValue:workout.totalEnergyBurned]
                                                           startDate:workout.startDate
                                                             endDate:workout.endDate]];
[healthStore addSamples:workoutSamples toWorkout:workout completion:nil];
```

That way there's at least only active energy burned sample. Now you'll get 445 kcal vs 445 kcal.

In my tests with 3rd party apps, I've found that most do add the active energy burned samples, but some, like Nike Running, do not.

A hacky workaround for this would be to pull out all of the active energy samples for a workout (you'll have to use `startDate` and `endDate` because `predicateForObjectsFromWorkout` has similar issues as noted above), then if there aren't any samples, assume that the source did not create active energy samples for that workout and add the workout's `totalEnergyBurned` to the active energy burned sum for the day.

Comment: @mflac you should consider filing a radar (https://bugreport.apple.com) against HealthKit for this as it makes the HealthKit data unusable. Feel free to dupe against mine: rdar://21584885

Comment: That is quite a bug! The workout I referenced above was using the app Runtastic. Interestingly, sometimes even using the  Apple Watch Workouts app, this would also occur although mysteriously sometimes later(the next day!) the data would appear in the activeEnergy! I can not conceive of how this happens. I will file a radar also.

Comment: I filed rdar://21856618

Comment: Isn't total energy burned = active energy burned + resting energy?